# Implement a Stack using Arrays and Linked List

Tags: arrays, stack

How do I implement a stack of element S={10,20,30,40} using arrays and Linked list diagrammatic ally. Regards

Comment: Have you searched the web for that?

Comment: Yes no similar example

Comment: Would you want to implement the stack with only linkedlist?